# How to minimize this ajax code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to minimize this ajax code that I am usually using when I am developing a system. Can somebody show me the shorthand version of ajax code like this? Thanks for the help. Below is my ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>superadmin/insert_ajax_currencies",
    dataType:"json",
    data: $("#currencies").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        if(data=='success'){
          alert('Success');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're trying to minimize that code, you're spending WAAAAAY too much time on trivial/useless optimizations.

Comment: I mean,something like to shorten it.

Comment: It looks pretty good as-is. You might save a line or two by using [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) instead, but that's about it. Also, this might be a better question for the folks over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: i dont know that you can minimize this code or not, but i think you should add `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           alert("Error")                                  
         }, `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely shorten it, eliminating the "type:", "url:" etc. tags. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/